# used XSLT to transform JSON documents into other formats

Tags: c#, json, xml, xslt

i get http answer which was in xml format,and  which quantizes the sessionID

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<MResponse>
     <Login>
         <SessionId> xxfffff </ sessionId>
     </ Login>
</ MResponse>
```

in my  c # project  I used XSLT to transform XML documents into other formats (like transforming XML into HTML

```
<body style = "margin: 0;" >
         <table border = "0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "0" bordercolor = "# 00FF00">
           <xsl: for-each select = "mResponse / mCatalog / asset [1]">
             <Tr>
               <xsl: apply-templates select = "../ child :: * [1]">
                 <xsl: with-param name = "sessionId" select = "/ mResponse / sessionId / text ()" />
               </ Xsl: apply-templates>
             </ Tr>
           </ Xsl: for-each>
         </ Table>
       </ Body>
```

the http response will be json format

```
{
     "sessionId": "xxxxxffff"
}
```

is there a solution with editing  XSLT file that allows me to recover the sessionId

Answer (score 1):

I've only looked at this very briefly, and I only started working Wicket myself a few months back, but I have a feeling my first impressions could be worth a try. If you study [this tutorial](http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage;jsessionid=9104D17EE488111CAAE5ED1112A73C8B?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.Index&source=PageablesPage.java) carefully (together with the accompanying HTML), it would seem that the PageableListView and the AjaxPagingNavigator are added to a WebMarkupContainer, as oppose to the page directly. This mark-up container, representing the whole table element in the HTML, is then added to the page :-) Maybe give that a try? :-) Furthermore, the tutorial also uses a wicket extend element and the Navigator is inside the tfoot element of the table. I would recommend copying the tutorial to the letter, and then adding your bespoke model so it works in the context in which you require it. Good luck :-)